# Preventing JQuery Sortable Propagation when hovering over fixed HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-events

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent sortable dragging and propagation when hovering over a fixed element at the bottom of the page.

Off hand, I'm not sure what the best and simplest way to do this would be.

I've created a simple example outlining the issue here:
http://jsfiddle.net/arpowers/kSCQU/1/

Sortable code:

```
jQuery('.sortable_area').sortable({
  items: ".sortable",
  dropOnEmpty: true,
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  forceHelperSize: false,
  connectWith: ".column",
  placeholder: "placeholder",
  cursor: "move",
  tolerance: "pointer",
});​
```

And there is a simple HTML element fixed to the footer of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Sortable has an option [containment](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#option-containment). Set `containment: '.container'` while initializing your sortable element and add the property `margin-bottom: 251px;` in the class `container` (the fixed part total height). Then the element cannot be on your fixed part and it should prevent any event raised from sortable.